# Need Solution to a Regex Issue

Tags: regex

- 1 Sample Text 7"
- "2 Sample Text 7"
- Sample Text 7
- Sample Text 7 2
- Sample Text 7" 2
- 2 "Sample Text Without A Number" 2
- 1 "Sample Text Without A Number" 1

I need to grab

```
Sample Text 7
```

or

```
Sample Text Without A Number
```

from each of these instances. Sample Text is a string of alphabetic characters that can sometimes include a 7.

I am fairly inexperienced with RegEx and am wondering what resources I could use to complete this task?

**EDIT:** It seems there are some formatting issues with the site itself and I need to account for this being a case;

> ```
>               2 Sample Text Note The Tabs And Spacing
> ```

Comment: *I need to do X* is not a complete question.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/30

Comment: This is almost what I need. The actual text isn't "Sample Text", it would be any alphabetic combination of letters and spaces which may include the number 7 (ie:A Name, Here Is Some More Text, Here Is One With 7 In It, etc).

Comment: Is the string `777777` valid or not?

Comment: Realistically, no, unless including it would be easier. The case shouldn't come up in practice, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
\b[a-zA-Z7]+[a-zA-Z7\s]*[a-zA-Z7]+\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rD9yX0/2)